# Ошибка 424. Требуется Объект

Tags: vba

Всем привет. 
Нужно написать макрос на VBA проверки значений, но, увы, я совсем не понимаю сути этого языка. Я много пишу на Питоне, ЯваСкрипте и немного на Яве и С++. 
Я много видел ситуаций, но ошибки ВБА просто ставят в ступор... :)
Собственно код

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    BasicRequirements (ActiveCell)

End Sub

Sub BasicRequirements(currentCell)

    If Cells(currentCell.row, currentCell.Column - 1).Value = "Александр" Then
        Debug.Print "Yes"
    Else
        Debug.Print "No"
    End If


End Sub
```

При выполнении получаю ошибку с требованием какого-то объекта... Какого? Где он должен быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема с вызовом `Cells(currentCell.row, currentCell.Column - 1)` в случае, когда `currentCell.Column` равен `0`.

Попробуйте добавить проверку на граничные значения.

Upd.

На самом деле главная проблема с неправильным вызовом. Должно быть так:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    BasicRequirements ActiveCell
End Sub

Sub BasicRequirements(currentCell)
    If Cells(currentCell.Row, currentCell.Column - 1).Value = "Александр" Then
        Debug.Print "Yes"
    Else
        Debug.Print "No"
    End If
End Sub
```

Проверка на то, что `currentCell.Column` больше нуля тоже нужна.

Comment: Увы, даже если оставить в теле функции только `Debug.Print currentCell.row`, результат тот же.

Comment: @Skotinin, я нашёл проблему и обновил ответ. При вызове ```BasicRequirements``` круглые скобки не нужны. Люблю VBA.

Comment: Я тоже пару секунд назад дошел до этого. :) Теперь гуглю, когда они нужны, а когда нет.

Comment: @Skotinin если еще не нагуглили. Круглые скобки нужны, когда либо идет присваивание переменной значением функции, т.е. `s = BasicRequirements(ActiveCell)`, либо если возвращаемое значение не используется, но для вызова функции используется `Call`, т.е. `Call BasicRequirements(ActiveCell)`

Answer (score 4):

В Вашем варианте по умолчанию *ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Value*. Вы передаете в процедуру значение ячейки

Меняем:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    BasicRequirements (ActiveCell.Offset(, -1).Value)
End Sub

Sub BasicRequirements(s As String)
    If s = "Саня" Then
        Debug.Print "Yes"
    Else
        Debug.Print "No"
    End If
End Sub
```

Если передать ячейку как объект:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    BasicRequirements ActiveCell
End Sub

Sub BasicRequirements(r As Range)
    If r.Column = 1 Then Exit Sub

    If r.Offset(, -1).Value = "Саня" Then
        '.....'
    End If
End Sub
```

Не стесняйтесь ставить в начале модуля *Option Explicit* и объявлять переменные. Помогает избегать многих ошибок.

Comment: Использовал вариант с `Call`, однако дальнейшее решение задачи показало, что "Чем глубже в лес, тем гуще партизаны" и решил удалить все макросы и сделать на формулах, списках и условном форматировании иначе не успею в срок. А еще потом все это дело поддерживать надо будет :)